# Assigning a String to a String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I am trying to assign each string a user inputs to a String array. The entire thing is in a `for` loop and is evaluated by the index of the array. My code is:

```
String skillAssign[] = new String[100];

    for (int i=0; isDone == false; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(skillAssign[i]);
        System.out.println(i);
        skillAssign[i] = keyboard.nextLine();
        if ((!(skillAssign[i].equalsIgnoreCase("stats"))) && (!(skillAssign[i].equalsIgnoreCase("done"))))
        {
            assignmentValue = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (((skillAssign[i].equalsIgnoreCase("health"))) && (skillPoints - assignmentValue >=0))
            {
                System.out.println("Added " + assignmentValue + " points to Health!");
                skillPoints = (skillPoints - assignmentValue);
                newMaxHealth = (assignmentValue + newMaxHealth);
            }
        //code that evaluates the string located inside the skillAssign[i] for other stats
    }
```

The first string evaluates properly, but when I go to input the second string, I get java.util.InputMisMatchException. How can I get it so it assigns a string to each index of the array inputted by the user, then evaluate it? (I think I got the evaluation part though)

I tried to limit the post to relevant code, so things like isDone are omitted, but isDone is changed to true when `done` is typed and keyboard is constructed with `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner` all other variables are set to 0 except for skillPoints

Comment: You've provided too little information to solve the issue. You haven't told what is `isDone`. Also, what else are you doing inside the `for` loop. Apart from that, please post the full stack trace.

Comment: You don't modify isDone in your loop at all. Also `isDone == false` can be better represented as `!isDone`.

Comment: isDone is modified in omitted code inside the loop, but it isn't really relevant as an exception is thrown after the second loop anyway.

Comment: When loooping, you need to have `isDone` modified, or you'll run into `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the abovementioned code, and this is what happens:

- We enter the loop.
- You are requested to input the first string (through `keyboard.nextLine()`). I inputted '*health*'.
- You are requested to input an integer (through `keyboard.nextInt()`). I inputted '*40*'.
- We re-enter the loop.
- You are requested to input an integer (through `keyboard.nextInt()`).
- ...

It seems that I'm not asked to input the second string, but instantly the integer.

I do not know why it is, but it looks like `nextInt()` causes the next `nextLine()` to be skipped.

Maybe you can replace

```
assignmentValue = keyboard.nextInt();
```

with

```
try {
    assignmentValue = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
}
catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
    throw new InputMismatchException(exc.getMessage());
}
```

---

**EDIT**
I saw [a post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19381036/507738) which briefly mentions why `nextLine()` after `nextInt()` is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

i believe this is closer to your intention. this way the reference to your keyboard input that nextLine grabs isn't lost on each iteration, but remains preserved in a new String instance. correct?

```
System.out.println(i);
String getMe = keyboard.nextLine();
skillAssign[i] = new String(getMe);
System.out.println(skillAssign[i]);
```

Comment: If I use that method, wouldn't it only work once because I can't make another String called getMe? (I'm kind of noob)

Comment: getMe is a local variable inside the loop, meaning on each iteration it is served new born without any link to its existence in the previous iteration.

Comment: if that's too confusing omit getMe, and use skillAssign[i] = new String(keyboard.nextLine());

Comment: `String skillAssign[] = new String[100];` doesn't allocate memory for your future strings acquired from the keyboard. it just reserves references that will once you get those strings be used to access them. once there's the actual string to be referenced you have to make an instance that will hold actual characters of it. that is done with that `new String(getMe);`